# OSM Centrer ten in Info Window

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to center text in Info Window I did this :

```
@Override
public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {

    mapView.getOverlays().remove(mPin);
    updateFields();
    mapView.getOverlays().remove(activeItemizedIconOverlay);
    mapView.getOverlays().remove(activeItemizedIconOverlay1);
    mPin.hideInfoWindow();
    mapView.getOverlays().remove(mPin);
    mPin.setPosition(anotherItemizedIconOverlay1.getItem(index).getPoint());
    mPin.setTitle(anotherItemizedIconOverlay1.getItem(index).getTitle() + "  ");
    mPin.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), RotateMyBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.res2), Singleton.getInstance().listaVisible.get(currentNumber).azimuth)));
    mPin.showInfoWindow();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mPin);
    mapView.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

And all the time a text in widow is on the left side

Comment: How is this code supposed to "center text in InfoWindow"? You are only displa one pin, with title, icon and default info window. I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. Maybe a screen-shot could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the design of the default InfoWindow layout doesn't fit your need, you can define and use your own bubble layout. 
See some advices [here](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2#9-creating-your-own-bubble-layout)